# Why does Firefox see my wordpress pages as feeds?

Tags: wordpress, firefox

Every time I click on "Discussion" and "Live Support" on my site http://riskeraser.com/ firefox pops up a "Live Bookmark" subscribe box.  These links are wordpress pages, not feeds.

Both IE and Chrome work fine, it's just firefox (3.6.12) giving me problems.

Comment: I can't comment on your problem, but the service looks great. One small thing, I just ran it on a couple of sites. It reports a "non-optimal" result even if all the domains I see in the list belong to the same site. The perfect way here would be to say "an optimal result will show only domains that belong to you". All in all, great work.

Comment: Can you remove the "hello world" from before the doctype to exclude funny quirks mode stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/firefox-and-rss-feed-issues). Try to clean out cache *(wp-content/cache/)* and configure theme and plugins.